# Angular2 If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am getting this error from Angular 2

> core.umd.js:5995 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in app/model_exposure_currencies/model_exposure_currencies.component.html:57:18
> caused by: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name
> attribute must be set or the form
> control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Example 1:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
```

Example 2:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

```html
<td *ngFor="let lag of ce.lags">
    <div class="form-group1">
        <input name="name" [(ngModel)]="lag.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" required>
    </div>
</td>
```

This is how I use form tag:

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Comment: cosider awarding one of the answers as the correct one

Answer (score 568):

If ngForm is used, all the input fields which have `[(ngModel)]=""` must have an attribute **name** with a value.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="something">
```

### Standalone

By setting `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` one tells Angular something like, ignore the form and/or `ngForm`, just bind it to `firstname` variable please.

However, if `form`-tag was used by mistake (like in my case sometimes), changing `form` to `div` is another option (but only if your styles don't need `form`-tag).

Comment: search for 'name attribute'  in this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html

Comment: does the name attribute have to have a unique value?

Comment: From Angular 5 documentation (https://angular.io/guide/forms): "Defining a name attribute is a requirement when using [(ngModel)] in combination with a form."

Comment: Applicable to Angular 7 too!

Comment: this answer helped me 2 times but why name filed is important

Comment: This (https://angular.io/guide/forms#the-ngform-directive) explains how the name field is used internally

Comment: I'd like to add that it will only work if ngModel comes first before the name.

Comment: Still applicable to Angular 8 and Angular 9!! :)

Comment: I was receiving the error `ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
` and this answer solve my problem.

Comment: I'm getting the same error even when my input field has the name correctly, its a form with conditional rendering fields.

Answer (score 63):

As every developer have a common habit, not to read the complete error, just read the first line and start looking for answer from someone else :):) I am also one of them, that's why I am here:

Read the error, clearly saying:

```
Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

What more we need to understand this error?

Use any one option everything will work smooth.

Comment: An explanation of the implication/effect of each alternative would be useful - choosing one of the two arbitrarily doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Here's a good explanation for `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}`:https://stackoverflow.com/a/38368261/3135317.  In my case, I got the dreaded ` ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must...` error when I had an `*ngFor* for a nested array.  The model binding was fine, the template barfed.  "Example 1" *COULDN'T* have worked; "Example 2" was perfect.

Comment: This answer helped me twice in the same week (it apparently didn't stick the first time) ;)

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the solution lies in the error itself and I couldn't read it in the first glance as again mentioned in the answer :) Thanks, It worked.

Answer (score 39):

In my case the error happened because below in html markup one more line existed without the **name** attribute.

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" #form="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="metaScript" />
        ... 
        <input id="input2" [(ngModel)]="metaScriptMessage"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

But the browser still reports the first row has the error. And it's difficult to discover the source of mistake if you have other elements between these two.
[image: screenshot of chrome devtools showing the error]

Answer (score 34):

Both attributes are needed and also recheck all the form elements has "name" attribute. if you are using form submit concept, other wise just use div tag instead of form element.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="something">
```

Answer (score 20):

I noticed that the Chrome developer tool sometimes only underlines the first element in swiggly red even if it is correctly set up with a name. This threw me off for a while.

One must be sure to add a **name** to **every** element on the form that contains ngModel regardless of which one is squiggly underlined.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That took me a while!

Answer (score 19):

When you clearly look at the console, it will give you two examples. Implement any of these.

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}">
```

**or**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
```

Comment: Don't just choose any, you have to understand what you're doing

Comment: @User2585, I agree with you but will you please elaborate the difference? I find everyone is suggesting to use "name" attribute. But No one explaining what exactly is the significance of using "name" attribute?

Comment: @PrajjwalGupta If you want the ngModel to part of the ngForm, you need to give it (the form control) a name, then the form value will have a property with the given name (in this case first) with the value of the input. If for some reason you don't want the ngModel to part of the ngForm, you can specify [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}", and then you don't a name

Answer (score 12):

It's quite easy for a fix.

For me, we had more than one inputs in the form. We need to isolate the input / line causing error and simply add the `name` attribute. That fixed the issue for me:

**Before:**

```
<form class="example-form">

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
```

---

```
      <mat-select placeholder="Select your option" [(ngModel)]="sample.stat"> <!--HERE -->
```

---

```
          <mat-option *ngFor="let option of actions" [value]="option">{{option}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Enter number</mat-label>
```

---

```
      <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter number" aria-label="Number"
        matInput [formControl]="myFormControl" required [(ngModel)]="number">  <!--HERE -->
```

---

```
    </mat-form-field>
```

---

```
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isRight">Check!</mat-checkbox> <!--HERE -->
```

---

```
  </form>
```

**After:**
i just added the `name` attribute for `select` and `checkbox` and that fixed the issue. As follows:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select your option" name="mySelect" 
  [(ngModel)]="sample.stat"> <!--HERE: Observe the "name" attribute -->

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter number" aria-label="Number"
        matInput [formControl]="myFormControl" required [(ngModel)]="number">  <!--HERE -->

<mat-checkbox name="myCheck" [(ngModel)]="isRight">Check!</mat-checkbox> <!--HERE: Observe the "name" attribute -->
```

As you see added the `name` attribute. It is not necessary to be given same as your `ngModel` name. Just providing the `name` attribute will fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need import { NgForm } from @angular/forms in your page.ts;

Code HTML:

```
<form #values="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="function(values)">
 ...
 <ion-input type="text" name="name" ngModel></ion-input>
 <ion-input type="text" name="mail" ngModel></ion-input>
 ...
</form>
```

In your Page.ts, implement your funcion to manipulate form data:

```
function(data) {console.log("Name: "data.value.name + " Mail: " + data.value.mail);}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required minlength="4" #name="ngModel" ngModel>
<div *ngIf="name.errors && (name.dirty || name.touched)">
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger form-alert">
        Please enter a name.
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!name.errors.minlength" class="alert alert-danger form-alert">
        Enter name greater than 4 characters.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For everyone who don't panic with the error message itself, but just googling for the explanation why example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132189/angular-5-using-filter-in-select-tag-with-pipe) doesn't work (i.e dynamical filtering doesn't occur when the text is typed into the input field): it will not work until you will add the name parameter in the input field. Nothing points to the explanation why pipe isn't working, but the error message points to this topic and fixing it according to the accepted answer makes the dynamical filter working.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't mention the version you're using, but if you're using rc5 or rc6, that "old" style of form has been deprecated.  Take a look at this for guidance on the "new" forms techniques: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to display the information in the form you would like, you need to give those specific inputs of interest names. I'd recommend you do have:

---

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)"> ...
<input **name="firstName" ngModel** placeholder="Enter your first name"> ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the solution was very simple. I changed the `<form>` tag into a `<div>` and the error goes away.

Comment: This is because you are removing the form, thus removing all the features the form provides.

Comment: @astro8891 me no need feature

Answer (score 2):

```html
<select name="country" formControlName="country" id="country" 
       class="formcontrol form-control-element" [(ngModel)]="country">
   <option value="90">Turkey</option>
   <option value="1">USA</option>
   <option value="30">Greece</option>
</select>
```

```html
name="country"
formControlName="country" 
[(ngModel)]="country"
```

Those are the three things need to use ngModel inside a formGroup directive.

Note that same name should be used.

Answer (score 1):

add standalone : true in ngmodel field like this

```
 <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="gender" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                            <mat-radio-button value="Male">Male</mat-radio-button>    
                            <mat-radio-button value="Female">Female</mat-radio-button>  
                        </mat-radio-group>
```