# How do I clear an input box with `ngModelChange`

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

How do I clear, or edit an input box with `ngModelChange`?

I have a pluncker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/oc1Q7lkEkXNxSag6Kcss/

My angular calls are in `template-driven-form.ts`

This is my HTML:

```
  <h1>(ngModelChange) Example:</h1>
  <p>
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input type="tel"  
      [(ngModel)]="expiration"
      (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
      name="expiration"
      required>
  </p>
```

This the angular code:

```
expiration: string = '';

onChange(event) {
  if (this.expiration) {
    let expiration = this.expiration.toString();
    expiration = expiration.replace(/[^0-9\\]/g, '');
    if (expiration.length > 2) {
      expiration += '\\';
    }
    this.expiration = expiration;
  } else {
    this.expiration = '';
  }
}
```

What I am trying to implement a expiration date for a credit card.
If someone enters something other than a digit I should ignore that input. If I get more than 3 digits I want to add a `\`.

But currently `ngModelChange` is not functioning the way I would expect. I put in letters and they are added to the input box.
I try to update the model `expiration = ''` but the letter persist in the input even though I have `[(ngModel)]=expiration`.

edit: I made an update to use tel, as `\` would not work on an input type `number`. But the line of code to update the model `this.expiration = expiration` does not work.

Comment: If you down vote please explain why the question is a problem to you. Other wise that is just trolling.

Answer (score 1):

The Banana-in-a-box syntax `[(ngModel)]` is a shorthand syntax for `[ngModel]="expiration"` and `(ngModelChange)="expiration=$event"`.

I would not recommend using both at the same time. Try to use only `[ngModel]` in combination with `(ngModelChange)`

**Update**
I did quite a hack :) but u can take a look at it:
https://plnkr.co/edit/6e9UyKlhjaXVvZ0cEnlh?p=info

- Within the form the name attribute is required
- I used the `(keydown)` event to filter alphanumeric keyboard events
- In the `format` method I step through the characters and add the `/`

  ```
  <input type="text"  
    name="mynubmer"
    (keydown)="onKeydown($event)"
    [ngModel]="format(expiration)"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
    expiration="expiration"
    required>

  onKeydown($event) {
    console.log($event)
    // filter a-zA-z
    if ($event.keyCode >= 65 && $event.keyCode <= 90) {
      $event.preventDefault();
   }
  }

  format(value) {
    if (value) {
      return value
        .split('')
        .map((character, index) => ((index+1) % 3 === 0) 
            ? character + '/'
            : character)
        .join('');
    }

    return value;
  }

  onChange(event) {
    this.expiration = event.split('').filter(char => char !== '/').join('');;
  }
  ```

Comment: Isn't it `(ngModelChange)="expiration = $event"`?

Comment: I have tried `[ngModel]="expiration"` that does not work either.

Comment: @Whitecat - It may depend on how you implemented `onChange(event)`. If you use `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`, then you should do something like this: `onChange(value) { this.expiration = value; ... }`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan that is exactly the question I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because you need to add the attribute "name" to your input. Both ngmodel and name are required as @Vinayak talked in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296665/7733724

I added `name="expiration"` in your plnkr (template-driven-form.ts) and event has begin to work.

For me it is working as you want I think:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

 @Component({
selector: 'template-driven-form',
template: `
<section>
  <h1>(ngModelChange) Example:</h1>
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitTemplateBased()">
  <p>
    <label>Number:</label>
    <input type="number"  
      [(ngModel)]="expiration"
      (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
      expiration="expiration"
      required
      name="expiration">
  </p>
  </form>
</section>
`
})

export class TemplateDrivenForm {

expiration: string;

onChange(event) {

  if (this.expiration) {
    let expiration = this.expiration.toString();
    expiration = expiration.replace(/[^0-9\\]/g, '');
    if (expiration.length > 2) {
      expiration += '\\';
    }
    this.expiration= expiration;
  } else {
    this.expiration = '';
  }
  alert(this.expiration);
}
 }
```

Comment: It acts differently for both chrome and safari. In safari it does not work.