# Mat Input two way binding to value property not working

Tags: angular, angular6

I have created a Mat Input control and done a 2 way binding of it's value property to a property on my controller but when I type in the input the bound property is not updated.

Stack blitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ojsjo

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input" [(value)]="currentValue">
  </mat-form-field>

  <h1>{{currentValue}}</h1>
</div>
```

Why is the bound property not updating?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]` (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7ojsjo-uuni3i) for a demo).

```
<input matInput placeholder="Input" [(ngModel)]="currentValue">
```

[This article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#two-way-data-binding-in-a-nutshell) explains how the equivalent behavior can be obtained with a combination of `[value]` and `(input)`.

Comment: Why does value not work?  It works this way with select control.

Comment: See [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html#two-way-data-binding-in-a-nutshell) for an explanation of `[(ngModel)]` being the equivalent of `[value]` and `(input)`.

Comment: I had to add "name" to make it working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462057/1266873