# Angular ng-reflect-model shows correct value but not reflecting in input element

Tags: angular, performance

Trying to output the array of data to the form. However, all the input elements only showing the last array value. I check the ng-reflect-model value which is correct, but not the input element. But, if I remove the form element, the result display correctly.

thanks

Data that is need to be output

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 17, museum_id: 2, day: "Sunday", hour: "asdg"}
1: {id: 18, museum_id: 2, day: "Monday", hour: "ge"}
2: {id: 19, museum_id: 2, day: "Tuesday", hour: "g"}
3: {id: 20, museum_id: 2, day: "Wednesday", hour: "geg"}
4: {id: 21, museum_id: 2, day: "Thursday", hour: "eg"}
5: {id: 22, museum_id: 2, day: "Friday", hour: "ads"}
6: {id: 23, museum_id: 2, day: "Saturday", hour: "ga"}
```

This is my html page

```
<form class="container mt-3" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let hour of hours">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ hour.day }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hour.hour" id="hour" name="hour">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

ts file

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.hourService.getHoursById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.hours = data;
      console.log(data);
    },error => console.log(error));
  }
```

element

```
<input _ngcontent-ecy-c47="" type="text" id="hour" name="hour" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-reflect-name="hour" ng-reflect-model="asdg">
```

page display
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ger0V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `ngModel` inside a `Form` then name attribute is a must and if you use it inside a `ngFor` loop make sure it is unique. Example

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="hour.hour"
  id="hour"
  name="{{hour.day}}"
/>
```

Reference taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462057/1289713)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Vimal,
I found another way to solve this problem by create index.

```
<form class="container mt-3" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div *ngFor="let hour of hours; index as i">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="day" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">{{ hour.day }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hour.hour" id="hour" name="hour{{i}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
</form>
```