# Angular 2 Component with ngModel doesnt work

Tags: angular

Iam new in Angular 2,before posting I tried to search for a solution over the internet but I couldnt get solution.i will be thankful if some one will help me

my codes below works without ngModel

user.component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'user',
template: `<h3>Welcome {{name}}</h3>
 <p>EMAIL: {{email}}</p>
 <div *ngIf="showHobbies"> 
 <p>HOBBIES:</p>  
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
         {{hobby}}
      </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
`,
})

export class UsersComponent  {

username:string;
private name:string;
private email:string;
private hobbies:string[];
private showHobbies:boolean;

constructor(){
    this.username="";
    this.showHobbies=false;
    this.name="My name";
    this.email="My Email";
    this.hobbies=['swimming','watching movie','playing football'];
}

toggleHobbies(){
     if(this.showHobbies==true){
         this.showHobbies = false;
     }
     else {
         this.showHobbies = true;
     }
}

}
```

app.module look like this

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UsersComponent  }  from './components/users.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,UsersComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

my app.component look like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<user></user>`,
})

export class AppComponent  { }
```

The above code stop to work when am adding form with ngModule for 2way binding in user.component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    template: `<h3>Welcome {{name}}</h3>
     <p>EMAIL: {{email}}</p>
     <p>TEL: {{telephone}}</p>
     <button (click)="toggleHobbies()">{{ showHobbies ? 'Hide hobbies' : 'Show hobbies'}}</button>

    <div *ngIf="showHobbies"> 
     <p>HOBBIES:</p>  
        <ul>
           <li *ngFor="let hobby of hobbies">
              {{hobby}}
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

when am adding the form below other codes stops to works

```
<form>
   <label>Name</label> <br/>
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" />
   <p>Hello {{username}} </p>
</form>
`,
```

})

Comment: What error message you have? Did you tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to-a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the developer tools, in this case you would get a very explanatory error, to actually tell you exactly where the error is:

[image: ErrorMessage]

So this can be solved in two ways. Add the `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" />
```

or add `standalone:true`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UfyLsDPfwybxZlZrV0Id?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you get a template parse error because you don't have `username` variable in your UsersComponent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "doesn't work" is all but helpful. What is the exact behavior? Do you get any error message?