# <select> tag validates form with default value angular5

Tags: angular5

I am working on angular5 template driven forms.

Problem: I used select list in form, and provide the values array for select list from my demo.ts file. The  following are the options I provided:

```
this.states = []; 
this.states.push( {label:'Select State', value:''}); 
this.states.push( {label:'Maharashtra', value:'Maharashtra'}); 
this.states.push( {label:'AndhraPradesh', value:'AndhraPradesh'});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-4">
        <p-dropdown [options]="states"  name="pass_state" [(ngModel)]="applicant.pass_state" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
        [autoWidth]="false" #passstate="ngModel" required></p-dropdown>

        <div *ngIf="passstate.invalid && (passstate.dirty || passstate.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
          <div [hidden]="!attempt.hasError('required')">state is mandatory</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Question: I need to validate this form, but when I select default value form is getting submitted successfully with null values for states, I need to fill the mandatory sate.

Comment: whats is the value in `applicant.pass_state`

Comment: can you replicate this in https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: i passed  values in applicant object , so i used   "applicant.pass_state"  as ng-model value @elvis_ferns      here i used primeng <p-dropdown>

Comment: @BhagvatLande set the value as null and not empty string

Comment: thanks for reply @elvis_ferns  i tried that , in that case also form is get validated and in json i get sate:"null"

Comment: its because of [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" Refer to  answer given by @zpul (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to-a)

Comment: thanks @elvis_ferns you help is really appreciative ...solution is worked for me..thanku very much   ...i need to gives you thums up .. :)