# Angular 4 select all checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angular, select, checkbox

i am trying to implement select all checkbox which will select all the checkboxes which is fine but when i click on other checkboxes other than select all 
it will again select all checkboxes

Html file

```html
<div class="form-check mt-3">
  <label class="form-check-label text-dark font-weight-bold">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
       true}" (change)="selectAll()">
                Select All
                <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"> </span>
              </span>
              </label>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let a of name">

  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

    <!--------------------div to justify content --------------------->
    <div class="">

      <div class="form-check mt-3">
        <label class="form-check-label text-dark">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="a.selected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
       true}" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()">
                    Household Information
                    <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"> </span>
              </span>
                  </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-3">
        <label class="form-check-label text-dark">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="a.selected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
       true}" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()">
                    House Images
                    <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"> </span>
              </span>
                  </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check mt-3">
        <label class="form-check-label text-dark">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" [(ngModel)]="a.selected" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
       true}" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()">
                    Map Access
                    <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"> </span>
              </span>
                  </label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Ts file

```js
selectAll() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.name.length; i++) {
    {
      this.name[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
    }
  }
}

checkIfAllSelected() {

  console.log(this.name);

  this.selectedAll = this.name.every(function(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    return item.selected == true;
  })

}
```

Comment: Each checkbox uses the same model: `[(ngModel)]="a.selected"`. So when you check one of them, it updates all the checkboxes sharing that same model. If they need to be checked individually, you need to give a different model to each checkbox.

Comment: @AlexK like b.selected?

Comment: @AlexK and should i create a different model?

Comment: @AlexK No. Each a.selected will be managed separately by angular as it is being looped upon.

Comment: For each `a` in `name`, you create three checkboxes: Household Information, House Images, and Map Access. All three checkboxes refer to the same model: `a.selected`. You need to give a different model to each checkbox if they need to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`, and it should work.
For more information, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to-a) link.