# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" - not working with solutions

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created a template driven form. It's as follows

```
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <form #profileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendUpdatedData(profileForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" ngModel  #firstName="ngModel" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="{{profileData?.firstName}}">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" ngModel  #lastName="ngModel" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="{{profileData?.lastName}}">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organization">Organization</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel  #organization="organization"  class="form-control" id="organization" placeholder="Organization" value="{{profileData?.organisation}}">
      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then I added import {  FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; and  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ] for the relevant module of my component. Not only that , but also I added the above imports to app.module.ts But I'm getting the error

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"
```

Please don't duplicate this question. I tried other solutions as well. Can someone help me.

Comment: Please create a demo at https://stackblitz.com/ if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your organization must be ngModel

Change it to this

```
<form #profileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendUpdatedData(profileForm)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" ngModel  #firstName="ngModel" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="{{profileData?.firstName}}">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" ngModel  #lastName="ngModel" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="{{profileData?.lastName}}">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organization">Organization</label>
            <input type="text" ngModel  #organization="ngModel"  class="form-control" name="organization" placeholder="Organization" value="{{profileData?.organisation}}">
      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

and also you need to add name to each input, the name will be serve as your property name.

see stackblitz for the complete guide
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppkntl

Comment: Thank you very much John. It works. Could you please tell me why we need to add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to-a?answertab=oldest#tab-top, glad to help :)

Comment: sendUpdatedData(profileForm: any){
 console.log("Profile" + profileForm.value.firstName);
 }

I tried to access data in component like this. But It's not working .

Comment: see my updated answer, i just realized that using standalone is not suitable on your case

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML Template
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <form #profileForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendUpdatedData(profileForm)">
      <div class="form-group">




        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>

         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"
               [(ngModel)]="profileData.firstName" name="firstName"
               #firstName="ngModel"  placeholder="First Name">


      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName"
               [(ngModel)]="profileData.lastName" name="lastName"
               #lastName="ngModel"  placeholder="Last Name">

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <label for="organization">Organization</label>

             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization"
               [(ngModel)]="profileData.organization" name="organization"
               #organization="ngModel"  placeholder="Organization">


      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

// Ts Code

profileData = {}

Hope this works for you