# Problems with ngForm with ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When i don't add, I can navegate to Agenda but If I add this code

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="registrar( fAgenda )" #fAgenda="ngForm">
```

it shows me this error

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZQjb.png)

html:

```
 <ion-header class="ion-no-border">
      <ion-toolbar color="secondary">

    <ion-buttons  slot="start">
      
      <ion-button>
        <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
      </ion-button>

    </ion-buttons>
    
    <ion-title class="ion-text-center">AGENDA</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-grid >
  <form (ngSubmit)="registrar( fAgenda )" #fAgenda="ngForm">

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col >
          <ion-label>Seleccione Fecha</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="11" >
            <ion-item>
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="calendar"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Fechas Dispoibles</ion-label>
              
              <ion-datetime yearValues="2020" 
                            displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY"
                            placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
                            [(ngModel)]="registrarAgenda.fecha"
                            required>
              </ion-datetime>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        </ion-row>


        <ion-row>
          <ion-col >
            <ion-label>Seleccione el horario</ion-label>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="11">
      <ion-item>
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="alarm"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Horarios Dispoibles</ion-label>
              <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" 
                            minuteValues="0"
                           [(ngModel)]="registrarAgenda.hora"
                            required
                            ></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
    </ion-row>



      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12">
          <ion-item >
            <ion-label>Servicio De Búsqueda</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="busqueda" (ionChange)="onClick()" slot="start" color="secondary"></ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item> 
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>


    <ion-grid fixed *ngIf="busqueda === true">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="11" >
          <ion-label >Dirección</ion-label>
              <ion-input class="log" type="text" 
                        required 
                        [(ngModel)]="registrarAgenda.coords"></ion-input>
            
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>


      <ion-row>
        <ion-col >
            <ion-label>Seleccione el servicio</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
 

      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="11">
          <ion-item  *ngFor="let servi of servicio">
                  <ion-label>{{servi.nombre}}</ion-label>
                  <ion-checkbox slot="start" color="secondary"
                  (ionChange)="Checked($event, servi.nombre, servi.precio)"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    
        

    <ion-row >
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="full" routerLink="/home" color="danger">Cancelar</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-button expand="full" type="submit" color="secondary">Agendar</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

agenda.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Agenda, Servicio } from '../../interfaces/interfaces';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgendaService } from '../../services/agenda.service';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { UiServiceService } from '../../services/ui-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-agenda',
  templateUrl: './agenda.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agenda.page.scss'],
})
export class AgendaPage implements OnInit {

  registrarAgenda: Agenda = {
  servicio: null,
  fecha: null,
  coords: null,
  usuario: null,
  hora: null,
};

registrarServicio: Servicio = {
  servicio: null,
  monto: null,
};

servicio = [
  {
    nombre: 'Pulido',
    precio: '40000'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Completo',
    precio: '35000'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Motor',
    precio: '20000'
  },
  {
    nombre: 'Ducha y Aspirado',
    precio: '25000'
  },
];

checked = [];
precioArray = [];

  busqueda: boolean;

  constructor( private navCtrl: NavController,
               private agendaService: AgendaService,
               private uiService: UiServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(  ){

    console.log('Nuevo estado:', this.busqueda);
  }

 async registrar( fAgenda: NgForm){

   if ( fAgenda.invalid) { return; }

   const valido = await this.agendaService.agendar(this.registrarAgenda);

   if ( valido ) {

    this.uiService.presentToast('Su agenda se logro con exitos');
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home', { animated: true } );
    

  } else {
    // Mostrar alerta
    this.uiService.alertaInfo('No fue posible agendarse ');
    }
 }


 Checked( event, checkbox: string, precio: string ){

  if (event.target.checked  ) {

    this.checked.push(checkbox);
    this.precioArray.push(precio);

  } else {

    const index = this.removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox);
    const index2 = this.removeCheckedFromArray2(precio);
    this.checked.splice(index, 1);
    this.precioArray.splice(index, 1);

    }
  // console.log(this.checked);

  // console.log(this.precioArray);
  this.registrarServicio.servicio = this.checked;
  this.registrarServicio.monto = this.precioArray;
  console.log(this.registrarServicio.servicio);
  console.log(this.registrarServicio.monto);

  this.registrarAgenda.servicio = this.registrarServicio;
  console.log('Sevi:', this.registrarAgenda.servicio);
  // this.registrarAgenda.servicio.monto = this.precioArray;
  // this.registroUsuario.vehiculo = this.checked;
  }

 removeCheckedFromArray(checkbox: string) {
  return this.checked.findIndex((category) => {
    return category === checkbox;
  } );
}

removeCheckedFromArray2(precio: string) {
  return this.precioArray.findIndex((category) => {
    return category === precio;
  } );
}

emptyCheckedArray() {
  this.checked = [];
  this.precioArray = [];
}


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `name` attribute with `[(ngModel)]` will work.
For Ex:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" minuteValues="0" 
[(ngModel)]="registrarAgenda.hora" name="hora" required></ion-datetime>
```

Like this you should add name attribute too in all the input elements.