# No directive found with exportAs 'NgForm' Angular17

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form component:

```
<section class="">
  <form
    #loginForm="NgForm"
    (submit)="onSubmit(LoginForm)"
    class="flex flex-col mt-[10%] w-fit h-fit m-auto border-gray-200 border-2 p-5 justify-center items-center text-xl drop-shadow-md rounded-md gap-10"
  >
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="email"
      placeholder="email"
      type="email"
      name="Email"
      id="#login"
      required
      minlength="5"
      maxlength="20"
    />
    <p>{{ email }}</p>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input
      [(ngModel)]="password"
      placeholder="password"
      type="password"
      name="password"
      id="password"
      required
      minlength="5"
      maxlength="20"
    />
    {{ password }}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>

  </form>
</section>
```

and its component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseButtonDarkComponent } from '../../../../shared/components/base-button-dark/base-button-dark.component';
import { FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [BaseButtonDarkComponent, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './login-form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login-form.component.css',
})
export class LoginFormComponent {
  email: string = '';
  password: string = '';
  onSubmit(loginForm: NgForm) {
    console.log(loginForm.value);
    console.log(loginForm.valid);
  }
}
```

and i get `No directive found with exportAs 'NgForm'.`
if i add `NgForm`
to imports i get:

```
 The directive 'NgForm' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and
 cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule.
```

Tried adding FormsModule to the app.component.ts and in the layout components, inside this components is located, but it didnt work.
Also, i dont have @NgModule in Angular17.

How to fix it?

**Edit**:
if I use template from Angular docs:
https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

```
 template: `
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel" />
      <input name="last" ngModel />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
    <p>First name valid: {{ first.valid }}</p>
    <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
    <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>
  `,
```

i dont get error, why?

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365761/angular2-use-ngmodel-with-ngmodeloptions-standalone-true-to-link-to ?

Comment: thanks rir for answer; i modified the  ngModel but it still doesnt work..

Comment: As I remember, NgForm is exported from ReactiveFormsModule. So try to import this module.

Comment: i tried and it didnt help; also, theres no need to do it as it works without it in angular docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo `ngForm` should not be capitalize.

`#loginForm="NgForm"` should `#loginForm="ngForm"`.